# Error: Returned error: authentication needed: password or unlock

Tags: web3js

This is my code to send payment from my wallet to another wallet

```
var web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://localhost:8545'));
var addr = "0x...........................";
var pass = "thePassword#";
web3.eth.personal.unlockAccount(addr, pass);
const toAddress = withdrawalAddress; //address of the recipient
const amountToSend = 0000001233489520;//wei;
console.log("Amount in toWei : ", amountToSend);
var send = web3.eth.sendTransaction({from:addr,to:toAddress, value:amountToSend});
```

This code works fine and make payment successfully. But sometimes it give me error `Error: Returned error: authentication needed: password or unlock`

Since it works fine with same code and gives error with same code. Why this?

Comment: I think there is an extra parameter in `web3.eth.unlockAcount(addr,pass,dur)` that determines how long the unlock last, probably that is causing the error eventually.

Comment: how this parameter can be used?

Comment: `web3.eth.personal.unlockAccount(address, password, 600)
 .then((response) => {
  console.log(response);
 }).catch((error) => {
  console.log(error);
 });`

this is coming from: https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/issues/986

In web3.py you can just use web3.eth.unlockAcount(addr,pass,dururation=none)